# What does "Excute-only Code" mean in Keil uVision?

Tags: keil

I'm trying to understand the advanced usage of uVision. I saw an option under C/C++ tab in Options menu. What does this option do? Is there any webpage that I can use to search for tips like this?
Here is the screenshot from the app:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the option Execute-only Code is ticked, your code will be placed in **execute-only memory (XOM)**, which only allows instruction fetches, i.e. the processor can only fetch program code from that memory area to *execute*. All data accesses to the code area (both read and write accesses) will generate a fault. The main purpose of doing this is to prevent reading/stealing/reverse engineering the protected firmware.

More information about this can be found here:

[An introduction to eXecute-only-Memory](https://community.arm.com/developer/ip-products/processors/b/processors-ip-blog/posts/what-is-execute-only-memory-xom)

[Execute-only memory](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0471m/chr1368698326509.html)

Yes, you can find more development guidelines in the [ARM® Compiler Software Development Guide](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0471m/index.html) and [infocenter.arm.com](http://infocenter.arm.com) in general.

Comment: Thanks @DinhQC, by saying  "(both read and write accesses)" do you mean after programming my chip, I am not able to reprogram the chip ??

Comment: Hi @MohammadYousefi, you are still able to reprogram the chip with your debugger, but your program is not able to reprogram itself at runtime.